# deltaX tapers down from a negative but not from a positive

Tags: java, delta

I am making an asteroids like game. in my game I would like my players ship to apply a change in the deltaX when the key is pressed (propel the ship in whichever direction) and when the key is released then the deltaX will slowly taper off before the ship comes to a complete stop. This creates a sort of "drifting" effect

Can someone please tell me why this code only tapers the delta off when it is a negative but not when it is a positive? (If you are moving left the ship will drift left when you let go, but this does not work when moving to the right)

Here is the snippet of code affecting the deltaX.

```
    if (GamePanel.Left && Math.abs(deltaX) <= speed)
    {
        this.deltaX = (this.deltaX-1)*1.6;
    }
    else if (GamePanel.Right && Math.abs(deltaX) <= speed)
    {
        this.deltaX = (this.deltaX+1)*1.6;
    }
    else if (!GamePanel.Right && !GamePanel.Left && Math.abs(deltaX) >= 0) 
    {
            this.deltaX *= .39;
    }
```

Comment: Are you saying that deltaX does not taper when (GamePanel.Right && Math.abs(deltaX) <= speed) ?

Comment: !GamePanel.Right && !GamePanel.Left && Math.abs(deltaX) >= 0

Is when it does not taper down. I need it to come to a complete stop which it does but it doesn't slow to a stop it just abruptly stops.

Comment: What is the type of deltaX?

Comment: Double and the x position is an int